# Open external PDF file on android emulator

Tags: java, android, pdf, android-intent, android-emulator

I tried to open PDF files that have external links, but after Adobe reader is opening, it gives me that "The document path is not valid"

This is the code I wrote:

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                File file = new File("http://www.kb.nl/sites/default/files/docs/pdf_guidelines.pdf");
                                Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                intent.setDataAndType(path,"application/pdf");
                                try 
                                {
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                } 
                                catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) 
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
                                        getString(R.string.app_name), 
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
            }
        });
```

How can I open external PDF files in my emulator, my aim is to open pdf files which are inside my google drive.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This few lines do the  magic:

```
try {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("Url to pdf or other")));
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                //do something here
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File("http://www.kb.nl/sites/default/files/docs/pdf_guidelines.pdf");
```

http://www.kb.nl/sites/default/files/docs/pdf_guidelines.pdf is not a path to a `File`. It is a URL to a Web site. You cannot wrap a Web URL in a `File` object and expect it to work.

You can try using `Uri.parse("http://www.kb.nl/sites/default/files/docs/pdf_guidelines.pdf")` to get your `Uri` and seeing if Adobe Reader will support that, but I doubt it.

More likely, you need to download the PDF yourself, then use *that* `File` in the `Intent`.

Comment: thanks, 
Uri.parse("http://www.kb.nl/sites/default/files/docs/pdf_guidelines.pdf") didn't work.
How can I download the file, I think to open it from the SDcard is far beter.

Comment: @MedAmini: "How can I download the file" -- use `DownloadManager`, or `HttpURLConnection`, or any number of third-party HTTP wrapper libraries.

Comment: Hi, now i'm able to download the file, I have only a question, when writing this : File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/pdf_guidelines.pdf");  in which exact folder I should put my pdf file?

Comment: @MedAmini: That is up to you. If it is a file that the user should want to use independently of your app, use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` as your base. Otherwise, use `getExternalFilesDir()` (a method available on your `Activity`) as your base.